# How to do yearly comparison in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have dataframe which contains columns like **Month** and **Qty** as you can see in below table:

```
| Month    | Fruit  |  Qty   |

| -------- | ------ | ------ |

| 2021-01  | orange | 5223   |

| 2021-02  | orange | 23     |

| ......   | .....  | .....  |

| 2022-01  | orange | 2342   |

| 2022-02  | orange | 37667  |
```

I need to do sum of the **Qty** group by the **Fruit**. My output DF will be below table:

```
| Year | Fruit    | sum_of_qty_This_year  |  sum_of_qty_previous_year  |

| ---- | -------- | --------------------- | -------------------------- |

| 2022 | orange   |         29384         |             34534          |
| 2021 | orange   |         34534         |             93584          |
```

but there is a catch here, consider below table.

```
| current year  | jan   | feb   | mar   | apr   | may   | jun   | jul   | aug   | sep | oct | nov   | dec |      
| --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|         
| previous year | jan   | feb   |       | apr   | may   | jun   | jul   | aug   |     | oct | nov   | dec |
```

as you can see the data for mar and sep is missing in previous year. So when we calculate sum of current year, **Qty** should exclude the missing months. and this should be done for each year

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, sum}
import spark.implicits._

val df1 = Seq(
  ("2021-01", "orange", 5223),
  ("2021-02", "orange", 23),
  ("2022-01", "orange", 2342),
  ("2022-02", "orange", 37667),
  ("2022-03", "orange", 50000)
).toDF("Month", "Fruit", "Qty")

val currentYear = 2022
val priorYear = 2021
val currentYearDF = df1
  .filter(col("Month").substr(1, 4) === currentYear)
val priorYearDF = df1
  .filter(col("Month").substr(1, 4) === priorYear)
  .withColumnRenamed("Month", "MonthP")
  .withColumnRenamed("Fruit", "FruitP")
  .withColumnRenamed("Qty", "QtyP")

val resDF = priorYearDF
  .join(
    currentYearDF,
    priorYearDF
      .col("FruitP") === currentYearDF.col("Fruit") && priorYearDF
      .col("MonthP")
      .substr(6, 2) === currentYearDF.col("Month").substr(6, 2)
  )
  .select(
    currentYearDF.col("Fruit").as("Fruit"),
    currentYearDF.col("Qty").as("CurrentYearQty"),
    priorYearDF.col("QtyP").as("PriorYearQty")
  )
  .groupBy("Fruit")
  .agg(
    sum("CurrentYearQty").as("sum_of_qty_This_year"),
    sum("PriorYearQty").as("sum_of_qty_previous_year")
  )

resDF.show(false)
//    +------+--------------------+------------------------+
//    |Fruit |sum_of_qty_This_year|sum_of_qty_previous_year|
//    +------+--------------------+------------------------+
//    |orange|40009               |5246                    |
//    +------+--------------------+------------------------+
```